# CheckBox state doesn't update

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm writing an application to take orders in a restaurant and on adding items, you can check some options with simple checkboxes. Howerver, when using a state for this checkbox (to capture the change and to update my optionList), the checkbox doesn't get toggled. I have the following code in my react application:

```
import {useState} from "react";

const Option = ({option, optionList, setOptionList}) => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState<boolean>(option.initialState);

    const changeOptions = () => {
        setChecked(!checked);
        if (checked) {
            setOptionList([...optionList] + option);
        } else {
            setOptionList([...optionList].filter(o => o.optionId != option.optionId));
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className={"option"}>
            <form>
                <input type="checkbox" id="option" checked={checked} onChange={changeOptions}/>
                <label htmlFor="option">{option.description}</label>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Option;
```

If I change the onChange function to

```
() => setChecked(!checked)
```

the checkbox works again but I really need an update of the optionList. What am I missing?

Comment: I think your design is a little odd. Instead of passing in `optionList` and `setOptionList` I would expect a prop `onCheck` and handle the `optionList` in the parent component. It's not the responsibility of this component to handle the state of its parent.

Comment: Agree with @Stanislas. @SergeantChesterfield Since you are passing the `optionList` as prop from parent and updating it in child again, your `Option` component probably gets re-rendered everytime you check or uncheck. 

As @stanislas mentioned, better do the setOptionList logic on the parent component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would let the parent component handle the optionList as follows:

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-cdn-yclrn?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
import { useState } from "react";

const descriptions = ["A", "B", "C"];

interface OptionProps {
  description: string;
  checked: boolean;
  onCheck: (checked: boolean) => void;
}

const Option = ({ description, checked, onCheck }: OptionProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id={description}
        checked={checked}
        onChange={() => onCheck(!checked)}
      />
      <label htmlFor={description}>{description}</label>
    </>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [optionList, setOptionList] = useState<string[]>([]);
  return (
    <form>
      {descriptions.map((d) => (
        <Option
          description={d}
          checked={optionList.indexOf(d) >= 0}
          onCheck={(checked) =>
            setOptionList((prev) =>
              checked ? [...prev, d] : prev.filter((i) => i !== d)
            )
          }
        />
      ))}

      <div>{optionList.join(",")}</div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

### Note

- I moved the form to the parent
- I gave each input its own ID and made each label point to that ID, since otherwise clicking the label would cause issues
- The input for the option has been simplified to only the description.
- I used [Functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to update the optionList (`setOptionList((prev) => ...)`), because I feel it's a much safer approach than relying on the last rendered value being the previous value (though in this case, it will not matter). Its good practice, especially when you start using `useState` in other hooks (e.g. `useEffect`, `useCallback`, ...).

### Motivation

`Option` shouldn't be aware of where it's being used. It's better to keep components like this as dumb as possible and let it's parent handle its behavior.
The advantage of this approach is that if the logic were to change, you'd only need to change one component (instead of both).

This is the [Single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), which is referenced in [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-1-break-the-ui-into-a-component-hierarchy)

Comment: Letting the parent handle the change makes more sense indeed. It seems I don't understand everything about the state changes, but this works, thanks!